# CALL_EXCEPTION error when calling a view function from React website

Tags: javascript, solidity, web3js, ethers.js

I have deployed the contract made using solidity locally using hardhat. When I get the contract and make a call to a view function using the contract in React website I get a CALL_EXCEPTION error in the console and also get a error in hardhat node console saying

> Warning: Calling an account which is not a contract

This is the function I use in React

```
const GetMessage = async () => {
    try {
        const {ethereum} = window;

      if (ethereum) {
        const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);
        const signer = provider.getSigner();
        const supplyChainContract = new ethers.Contract(
          contractAddress,
          contractABI,
          signer
        );

        let count = await supplyChainContract.GetCount();
        console.log(count.toNumber());

      } 
      else 
        setMessage("Ethereum Not Found");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return null;
    }
  };
```

This is the contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

import "../node_modules/hardhat/console.sol";

contract SupplyChain {
    uint256 public count;
    function GetCount() public view returns (uint256){
        return count + 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just using `npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js` instead of `npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network localhost`